# Invalid characters in command

Tags: vimscript

Which characters in a vimscript command are invalid?

Is there are blacklist or a whitelist of characters?

Currently, I've only come up with these characters that trigger the error

> Invalid command name

- `_`
- `-`
- `.`
- `!`
- `:`

Thanks!

Comment: +1 for saving me from the manual.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See `:help user-commands`

> All user defined commands must start with an uppercase letter, to avoid
>   confusion with builtin commands.  Exceptions are these builtin commands:
>           :Next
>           :X
>   They cannot be used for a user defined command.  ":Print" is also an existing
>   command, but it is deprecated and can be overruled.
>
> The other characters of the user command can be uppercase letters, lowercase
>   letters or digits.  When using digits, note that other commands that take a
>   numeric argument may become ambiguous.  For example, the command ":Cc2" could
>   be the user command ":Cc2" without an argument, or the command ":Cc" with
>   argument "2".  It is advised to put a space between the command name and the
>   argument to avoid these problems.
>
> When using a user-defined command, the command can be abbreviated.  However, if
>   an abbreviation is not unique, an error will be issued.  Furthermore, a
>   built-in command will always take precedence.